# Reduction of Order for Second Order Linear Homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please explain how to apply the reduction of order method to the following differential equation:

$ y''+(y')^3 siny =0$

I attempted the substitution $ u(y)=y'$ but this turned out a horrible answer, so I don't think this substitution is what's required.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** all non-constant solutions of $y'' + (y')^3 \cdot \sin y = 0$ are contained in solutions of $\frac{y''}{(y')^2} = - y' \cdot \sin y$. Do LHS and RHS remind you time derivative of some functions of $y'$ or $y$ ?